# Writing the NotORM Syntax

Tags: php, slim, notorm

I have a problem here in NotORM code.

This code are working well:

`$select = $db->pspaym->select("COUNT(*)")->where("F4","$textdate")->fetch();
                           $count = count($select);`

But this code here does not working:

`$select = $db->pssale->select("COUNT(*)")->where("F8","$textdate")->fetch();
                           $count = count($select);`
This code have an error message said:

"Trying to get property of non-object"

cannot resolve this problem.

all variables are not null.

thanks.

Comment: Where do you define $db on the second example?

Comment: the $db is from the dbcon.php. then I declare the $db as global. this is the code: `global $db`

Comment: I declare the global $db on the top of the page of the file where the codes are had been declared.

Comment: I see the problem now. when I echoing the first code that I had declare above, it is echoing the `$textdate` but the second does not echo a `$textdate`. I dont know why that happen.

Comment: I see the error now sir. it seems that when I declare an echo $textdate above the global $db, the date appears.this is the code: function count_sales($textdates) { echo $textdates; global $db; $select = $db->pssale->where("F8 = ?", $textdates)->fetch(); $count = count($select); echo count($select);

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count lines in a table, simply use:

```
$select = $db->pspaym->where("F4","$textdate");
$count = count($select);
```

The problem comes from your combination of `fetch()` and `count()` methods. Because of the ending fetch call, `$select` doesn't contain a Table object, but a Record object.

So `count($select)` will count the number of columns in your record. Normally, it should always returns 1 (because one field in the returned record).

For your information, if you want to be uselessly explicit, you may do something like this.

```
$record = $db->pspaym("F4","$textdate")->select("COUNT(*) AS c")->fetch();
$count = $record['c'];
```

But, that's the long way.